# recycle view does not update properly

Tags: java, android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

hi guys i am struggling 2 days with a recycle view 
i have a fragment include a recycle view i have a dialog fragment in this fragment and i want when dialog dissmissed recycle view update

this is ovvrerid on dissmiss method in  dialog fragment

```
 somefragment fragment = new somefragment ();
     var trance=Activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    trance.Detach(fragment);
                    trance.Attach(fragment);
                    trance.Commit();
```

after that i get new data in onstart and give it to adapter again and when i check with break point every thing is fine but still recycle dose not update

```
list = await DownloadDataFromServer<List<Cilinic>>(uri + Handel.CurrentCityId);

        myAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(list);
        myRecyclerView.SetAdapter(myAdapter);
          myAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

please help me out

Comment: Did you use LayoutManager in the code?

Comment: Why you create a new instance of your fragment? Can't you directly update adapter in the override dismiss method of fragment?

Comment: no on dissmiss is in another dialog fragment and i cant update recycle view in my main fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code

```
 RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    myRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

Comment: is list has data?

Comment: yes i check it out with break point and my data is in there but nothing happen!